# Not able to pass parameter to SSRS report from c# Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

From an aspx, I have code behind to call a SSRS report. Most of this code works, but now trying to pass a parameter it's not showing up in the report itself. Any ideas on next steps to debug this?

```
public partial class GenerateReports 
{
    . . .
    protected global::Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer rptViewer;
}

public partial class GenerateReports : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    . . .
    private void LoadReport(string reportName)
    {
        rptViewer.ServerReport.DisplayName = reportName;
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = LodgexConfigurationManager.ItemPath + reportName;

        rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("rptperiod", "1")); 

        rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you try   `rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("rptperiod", 1));` as it is integer and not string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A change to the ReportParameter as array works.

```
        rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] {
            new ReportParameter("ManifestPeriod", reportManifestPeriod)
        });
```